# Как скомпилировать .exe для Windows с GCC из-под Linux?

Tags: linux, c, windows, gcc

**Вопрос:** Я написал простой C-код для тестирования:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Translaaaaaatooooor\n");
    return 0;
}
```

И скомпилировал его с `gcc -c main.c`, но сгенерировался исполняемый файл (только для Linux) main.o. Если запустить его `./main.o`, он отобразит Translaaaaaatooooor.

Мой вопрос в том, как я могу скомпилировать main.c, чтобы Windows могла запускать его? В основном, как вы создаете `*.exe`-файл с GCC в подсистеме Linux?

Экзешник созданный командой `gcc -o translaaaatoooor.exe main.c` не работает в Windows.

Comment: а в чем проблема то?

Comment: Если Вы желаете делиться своими знаниями и накопленным опытом, вопрос и ответ следует разделить. Ответ должна быть оформлен именно как ответ (отдельное поле ввода).

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, оставив в нем текст собственно вопроса. А текст ответа разместите в ответе на свой же вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

**Перенесено из вопроса**

> Чтобы под Linux создать исполняемые файлы для Windows, необходимо
>   установить кросс-компилятор mingw:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
> ```
>
> Затем вы можете создать 32-разрядную версию .exe для Windows с
>   помощью:
>
> ```
> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o main32.exe main.c
> ```
>
> И 64-разрядную версию .exe для Windows:
>
> ```
> x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o main64.exe main.c
> ```
>
> Эти исполняемые файлы Windows не будут работать внутри подсистемы
>   Linux, только за ее пределами.

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786014/how-to-compile-executable-for-windows-with-gcc-with-linux-subsystem#38788588) [@MarkusLaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6600109)

Comment: А можно как то создать и для 32 бит и для 64? вот например если я на винде компилирую файл, он работает как на моей(64) так и на чужой(32), как сделать такое на Линукс? Т.е скомпилировать файл в виде .exe и для Windows 32 и для Windows 64bit?

Comment: @FormatC, если скомпилируете в 32 бита, то будет работать и на 64-битной Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Компиляция с флагом `-с` создает не исполняемый файл, а бинарник. Для компиляции исполняемого файла нужно использовать `-o`:

```
gcc -o 1 1.c -Wall
```

К тому же если вы просто хотите перенести скомпилированный файл из линукса в винду, то ничего не получится. Для работы в виндоус нужен `mingw`, если нужны сторонние библиотеки, то лучше установить еще и `msys`.